# jQuery not detecting window size correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so I have a set of images that on a big screen are not using the image slider. And when the screen goes below a certain width, the image slider is initiated.

At the moment, when I resize the window manually and play around dragging the size around it works well.

But, if I resize the window to a small size and hit `F5` then what should happen is that the page automatically recognises that it needs to initiate the image slider. What does happen is that the images load like this below and not an interactive image slider.

So the problem is that if the page is already under 939 then the bxSlider functionality doesn't work. It will put the images into a bullet-pointed list as below without actually adding the interactivity. It will also not deactivate the bxSlider when the screen is resized to above 939.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're using the `resize` event to trigger your code. The reason that doesn't work when you refresh at a small size is that after the page loads, you don't resize it again, so the resize event doesn't fire.

Resizing only triggers when you manually grow/shrink the browser, without refreshing the page.

To fix it, just trigger your current function on first page load (I can't see the code here, but presumably it checks the current browser dimensions and updates the page accordingly? If so, entirely safe and sensible to run at the start of page load).

Comment: Hi sorry I accidentally removed the code. I've added the code now, I think you are correct with what you are saying but I'm not sure how exactly to fix it in my code, I've been playing around for a few hours now.

Comment: Sorry to add more, but the code is being used in `checkWidth` as it does execute the `heading` related code at the bottom but doesn't quite initiate the bxSlider for some reason

Comment: Ah no problem, thanks for putting it back. Looks like the issue is just naming! The checkWidth() function is looking for IDs like `#image-holder` but the actual IDs in the HTML are `#image-holder2`

Comment: Sorry there are indeed 2 IDs it uses, I have just shown `#image-holder2` as an example but both `#image-holder` and `#image-holder2` are having the same problem. I have tried lots of different things but can't seem to get it to execute the `bxSlider` code so that it initialises the image slider

Comment: Ah okay. It looks like line 1413 in your fiddle is the issue. When I load that page at least, 3 of the 5 conditions are false, so the createSlider() function is never called. Are all of those CSS classes definitely present when the page is first loaded?

Comment: If I load the page with the window fully maximized, then yes they are all there. But it seems if the window is < 939px only the `bxslider` class is there. I'm not sure entirely because I thought if `bxslider` is there then it must initiate the image slider code as for it to have `bxslider` as a class then it must run the  `createSlider` function

Comment: Is this it? http://jsfiddle.net/2HJzC/5/ - The image-holder was missing the .acc-list class, and I deleted the 2 `hasClass` checks for image-holder2 because there is no image-holder2 in the fiddle (So that could never pass). Slider is initiating for me now at the small size.

Comment: Ah god thanks a lot, I must have removed the `acc-list` by accident when trying out different things to debug it. God coding is annoying sometimes! :P

Comment: Haha, no problem, glad it's sorted! Thanks for choosing this answer too :)

Answer (score 0):

try changing this

```
$(window).resize(checkWidth);
```

to

```
$window.on('resize', function() {
    checkWidth();
});
```

Comment: Still has the same behaviour, if I make the window under 939px and then hit F5 I get the image slider loading as in the picture above. And this also means that when I go to make the window bigger (above 939px) it doesn't return to how it should look either.

Comment: Not that I can see, and the `<ul>` correctly has the `bxslider` class when I check the element, but it isn't executed by bxSlider to make it as it should be above in the picture

Comment: I tried but using the bxSlider library as well I've struggled. I can show you the code by sending the file, but I've had no luck replicating any sort of behaviour in a JSFiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2HJzC/4/ Well this is just the code I have, but I can't tell if it is working correctly because it doesn't correctly implement the image slider

Comment: Hard to get anything replicating it in a jsfiddle it seems